# Trying to pick and throw an object in 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

me and my colleagues are creating a 2D sidescroller game in Unity with C#.
The player, is supposed to be able to pick objects (by touching them) and throw them.
Our plan is this:
1) make variables for the objects, their booleans and their rigid bodies.
2) verify if the object is touching the player
3) if it's true, then the object will parent to the player (setting their position to the player's hand).
4) to throw, the code will check if the player has the object (by using a boolean) and then it will unparent and throw by addforce.
The code doesn't have any errors and it works except on the throwing part (the player can grab and ungrab but can't throw).
The player can pick and unpick but not throwing and i don't understand why because the code looks right and the console doesn't show me any errors :/
Have a look to my code:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool ispicked1 = false;
    public GameObject pickable1;
    public Rigidbody2D pickable1rb;
    public GameObject Parent;
    public float force;

    void Start() {
        pickable1rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

     void Update() {
        if (ispicked1 == true) {
            pickable1.transform.position = Parent.transform.position;
        } 
      else if (ispicked1 == false) {
            pickable1.transform.parent = null;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1) && ispicked1 == true) {
            ispicked1 = false;
            pickable1rb.AddForce(transform.up * force, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {

        if (collision.gameObject.name == "pickable1") {
            Debug.Log("Tocou em objecto");
            ispicked1 = true;
            pickable1.transform.SetParent(Parent.transform);
        }
    }

}
```

Side question: i want the player to throw at the direction he's facing, what is the best way to do that? I can only choose between right, left or up :/

UPDATE:
I solved all the problems and i created a side script for the object to be thrown and they are 100% working! Here are the codes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool ispicked1 = false;
    public bool ispicked2 = false;
    public GameObject pickable1;
    public GameObject pickable2;
    public GameObject Parent;
    public bool isThrown = false;
    public ThrowableObject throwableinstance1;
    public ThrowableObject throwableinstance2;
    public bool isfull = false; 

    void Start() {
        throwableinstance1 = GameObject.Find("pickable1").GetComponent<ThrowableObject>();
        throwableinstance2 = GameObject.Find("pickable2").GetComponent<ThrowableObject>();
    }

     void Update() {
        if (ispicked1 == true) {
            pickable1.transform.position = Parent.transform.position;
            isfull = true;
        } 
      else if (ispicked1 == false) {
            pickable1.transform.parent = null;
        }

        if (ispicked2 == true) {
            pickable2.transform.position = Parent.transform.position;
            isfull = true;
        } else if (ispicked2 == false) {
            pickable2.transform.parent = null;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1) && ispicked1 == true) {
            ispicked1 = false;
            isThrown = true;
            throwableinstance1.Throw();
            isfull = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1) && ispicked2 == true) {
            ispicked2 = false;
            isThrown = true;
            throwableinstance2.Throw();
            isfull = false;
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {

        if (collision.gameObject.name == "pickable1" && isfull == false) {
            ispicked1 = true;
            pickable1.transform.SetParent(Parent.transform);
        }

        if (collision.gameObject.name == "pickable2" && isfull == false) {
            ispicked2 = true;
            pickable2.transform.SetParent(Parent.transform);
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the code to throw the pickable object:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThrowableObject : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Inventory inventoryinstance;
    public Rigidbody2D throwablerb;
    public Transform Player;
    public GameObject PickableObject;

    public EnemyHealth1 enemyhealth1instance;
    public EnemyHealth2 enemyhealth2instance;
    public EnemyHealth3 enemyhealth3instance;

    void Start()
    {
        inventoryinstance = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Inventory>();

        enemyhealth1instance = GameObject.Find("enemy1").GetComponent<EnemyHealth1>();
        enemyhealth2instance = GameObject.Find("enemy2").GetComponent<EnemyHealth2>();
        enemyhealth3instance = GameObject.Find("enemy3_leper").GetComponent<EnemyHealth3>();
    }

    public void Throw()
    {
        if(Player.localScale.x < 1)
        {
            throwablerb.AddForce(transform.right * -1);
        } else if(Player.localScale.x > 0)
        {
            throwablerb.AddForce(transform.right);
        }
    }

     private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "enemy1") {
                enemyhealth1instance.GetComponent<EnemyHealth1>().EnemyHealthbar1-= 1;
                Destroy(PickableObject);
    }
     if (collision.gameObject.name == "enemy2") {
            enemyhealth2instance.GetComponent<EnemyHealth2>().EnemyHealthbar2-=1;
            Destroy(PickableObject);
    }
 if (collision.gameObject.name == "enemy3_leper") {
            enemyhealth3instance.GetComponent<EnemyHealth3>().EnemyHealthbar3-=1;
            Destroy(PickableObject);
    }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
         if (col.gameObject.name == "enemy1_hitbox") {
            enemyhealth1instance.GetComponent<EnemyHealth1>().EnemyHealthbar1-=1;
            Destroy(PickableObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work" mean. It can be anything: nothing happens, it throws weirdly, the player color turns orange. Define current behaviour and desired behaviour.

Comment: Sorry sorry, basically the player can pick and unpick but he can't throw the object.

Comment: That isn't much more helpful, you basically just re-wrote what was written in the original post, hehe. Does the item drop to the ground when clicking Mouse1? Is the code triggering at all?

Answer (score 3):

While you're answering my question, I'll do some quick code reviewing:

Overall, it feels weird to be keeping track and maintaining "holding & throwing an item" in a class called "Inventory" that has references to a separate object, that is being held & a reference to the player. What is this script? The item, the player or a third party; a separate inventory? (Questions to ask yourself, you don't need to answer them - just think about it )

```
pickable1
pickable1object
pickable1rb
```

These variable names makes little sense to me in current context; why not just `isPickedUp`, `object`, `rb`?

---

```cs
if (pickable1 == true) {
    pickable1object.transform.position = Playerparent.transform.position;
}
if (pickable1 == false) {
    pickable1object.transform.parent = null;
}
```

pickable1 will not be both true and false, doing 2 ifs are just unnecessary computations. What you're looking for here is an if/else or if/elseif.
Furthermore, if you child it to the player, logically, shouldn't you NOT have to set the position every frame? Else, what's the purpose of childing?

---

```cs
void FixedUpdate() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)) {
        // [...]
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Logically, you shouldn't be checking for input in the fixed update since inputs are tied to a *frame*, meaning `Update()`. In this case, it may accidentally work reliably most of the time because you're not checking if the player CLICKED a button, rather you're checking if player is HOLDING a button. (`GetMouseButton` vs `GetMouseButtonDown`). If you were to check for if the player CLICKED a button in the FixedUpdate, it would only work on the few lucky frames where FixedUpdate and Update were running at the exact same time.

---

Regarding your question: The code looks alright, it's probably not behave in the way you expect. From what I can tell in the code it will...

- If player has picked up an item, it will have force added to it if holding down Mouse 1 for as long as player is holding down mouse.

Why nothing is happening may be due to inspector values being off. Debug the values of `force` and see if the code is triggering at all. Consider moving the `parent = null` code (or just remove the parenting alltogether).

It could also be that as soon as you push the item outside of the player, it falls down and triggers OnCollisionEnter and is grabbed by the player again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you use `transform.up` which will just cause it to throw upwards rather than the direction the player is facing. So you can use `transform.right` for the direction the player is facing. You can use both to create more of an arc.

You'll have some problems with pivoting with the way you have it setup.

What I recommend is to have two transforms which are children of the player to pivot the sprite properly. (You can change the position of the transform in the keyframes of the player's animation)

The code would look something like this:

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool carryingItem => pickedUpItem == null;
    private PickableItem pickedUpItem;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 throwingForce;
    [SerializeField] private Transform spawnPosition; //Should be a child of the player gameobject. This will be position of the object
    [SerializeField] private Transform handTransform; //Should also be a child of the player gameobject. This needs to be animated for the keyframes that move the hand

    void Update()
    {
        if (carryingItem && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            pickedUpItem.transform.SetParent(null);
            pickedUpItem.transform.position = spawnPosition.position;
            pickedUpItem.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.right * throwingForce.x + transform.up * throwingForce.y);
            pickedUpItem = null;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        var pickable = other.transform.GetComponent<PickableItem>();
        if (pickable && pickedUpItem == null) //This kind of depends on the game design because maybe you want to pick it up if you're carrying something already
        {
            pickedUpItem = pickable;
            pickable.transform.SetParent(handTransform);
        }

        pickable.transform.localPosition.Set(0,0,0);
    }
}
```

You set the picked up item to the parent where you want to be pivoted around.